# javascript code skips some lines from executing

Tags: javascript

What i want to achieve is, inserting text values from table cells in to 2 different sql table. They work if i comment the other one. But if i want to use the code above it's completely missing the first loop where y === 0 and second sql receives all values as undefined but i can print them just fine before sql.connect line.

Here is my code

```js
function update() {
  $('body').on('click', '#btnSave', function() {
    values = []
    $('input.form-control').each(function() {
      var valueNew = $(this).val();
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      values.push(valueNew);
    })

    for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++) {
      if (y === 0) {
        console.log(y)
        sql.close()
        sql.connect(config, err => {
          const request = new sql.Request()
          let editorTexts = $('#summernote').summernote()[0].value;
          console.log(editorTexts)
          request.query(`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('${values[1]}', '${values[0]}', '${editorTexts}')`)
          request.on('recordset', columns => {})
          request.on('row', row => {})
          request.on('error', err => {})
          request.on('done', result => {
            console.log(result.rowsAffected)
          })
        })
      } else {
        var table = $("#table tbody");
        for (var x = 0; x < table[0].rows.length; x++) {
          sql.close()
          sql.connect(config, err => {
            const request = new sql.Request()
            request.query(`INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14) VALUES ('${values[1]}', '${values[0]}', '${values[3 + (x*10)]}', '${values[4 + (x*10)]}', '${values[5 + (x*10)]}', '${values[6 + (x*10)]}', '${values[7 + (x*10)]}' ,'${values[8 + (x*10)]}','${values[9 + (x*10)]}', '${values[10 + (x*10)]}', '${values[2]}', '${values[11 + (x*10)]}', '${values[12 + (x*10)]}', '${+lastID[0]+1}')`)
            request.on('recordset', columns => {})
            request.on('row', row => {})
            request.on('error', err => {})
            request.on('done', result => {
              console.log(result.rowsAffected)
            })
          })
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the code is still running, but in asynchronous. Asynchronous code takes statements outside of the main program flow, allowing the code after the asynchronous call to be executed immediately without waiting.

Because sql function is async, you closed the connection before the first loop was done. E.g, when `y === 1`, the process of insertion when `y === 0` still running, and you close it, so the transaction was canceled.It's better for you to learn more about how asynchronous, callback, promise works

I don't know whether your sql client supported pooling or not. However, you should remove the line `sql.close()`. Closed it once after all transaction are done.

However, what I am concerning is, if y has only `0` and `1`, why do you do it in loop? It is better if you do it step by step like this:

```js
function update() {
  $('body').on('click', '#btnSave', function() {
    values = []
    $('input.form-control').each(function() {
      var valueNew = $(this).val();
      $(this).attr('disabled', true);
      values.push(valueNew);
    })

    // y === 0
    sql.connect(config, err => {
      const request = new sql.Request()
      let editorTexts = $('#summernote').summernote()[0].value;
      console.log(editorTexts)
      request.query(`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('${values[1]}', '${values[0]}', '${editorTexts}')`)
      request.on('recordset', columns => {})
      request.on('row', row => {})
      request.on('error', err => {})
      request.on('done', result => {

         // y === 1
         var table = $("#table tbody");
          for (var x = 0; x < table[0].rows.length; x++) {
            sql.connect(config, err => {
              const request = new sql.Request()
              request.query(`INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14) VALUES ('${values[1]}', '${values[0]}', '${values[3 + (x*10)]}', '${values[4 + (x*10)]}', '${values[5 + (x*10)]}', '${values[6 + (x*10)]}', '${values[7 + (x*10)]}' ,'${values[8 + (x*10)]}','${values[9 + (x*10)]}', '${values[10 + (x*10)]}', '${values[2]}', '${values[11 + (x*10)]}', '${values[12 + (x*10)]}', '${+lastID[0]+1}')`)
              request.on('recordset', columns => {})
              request.on('row', row => {})
              request.on('error', err => {})
              request.on('done', result => {
                console.log(result.rowsAffected)
              })
            })
          }
        })
      })
    }
  })
}
```

If you know how to work with [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise), it's better to wrap async task with Promise. It's safer and cleaner in code, like this:

```js
    function insertTable(values) {
      return sql.connect(config)
        .then((pool) => {
          const editorTexts = $('#summernote').summernote()[0].value

          return pool.request().query(`INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3) VALUES ('${values[1]}', '${values[0]}', '${editorTexts}')`)
        })
    }

    function insertTable1(x, values) {
      return sql.connect(config)
        .then((pool) => {
          return pool.request().query(`INSERT INTO table2 (col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10, col11, col12, col13, col14) VALUES ('${values[1]}', '${values[0]}', '${values[3 + (x*10)]}', '${values[4 + (x*10)]}', '${values[5 + (x*10)]}', '${values[6 + (x*10)]}', '${values[7 + (x*10)]}' ,'${values[8 + (x*10)]}','${values[9 + (x*10)]}', '${values[10 + (x*10)]}', '${values[2]}', '${values[11 + (x*10)]}', '${values[12 + (x*10)]}', '${+lastID[0]+1}')`)
      })
        })
    }

    function update() {
      $('body').on('click', '#btnSave', function() {
        const values = []
        $('input.form-control').each(function() {
          var valueNew = $(this).val();
          $(this).attr('disabled', true);
          values.push(valueNew);
        })

        // y === 0
        insertTable(values)
          .then(() => {
            // y === 1
            const table = $("#table tbody");
            const tasks = []
              for (var x = 0; x < table[0].rows.length; x++) {
                tasks.push(insertTable1(x, values));
              }

              return Promise.all(tasks);
          }).then((results) => {
            console.log("Inserted successfully");
          }).catch((err) => {
            console.error(err);
          });
      })
    }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your detailed answer! but it still won't pass to the second function of insertTable1. There is no error it just stops there, not printing anything before or after the function or inside the function edit: i tried the Promise way there is nothing happens after insertTable(values).then

Comment: Sorry, I fixed the code. Can you try again? Thanks. You should open Dev Tool Console to debug. I don't see your full source code, so I can debug myself

Comment: still won't work. Console is already open but nothings prints out. First function writes data but second one won't execute

Comment: Can you run console.log `tasks` array to see there are any item in it. Maybe the array is empty. Check if there is any row in table body too

Comment: i put test console.log just after insertTable(values)
      .then(() => { but i didn't executed either.

Comment: What sql library do you use? MSSQL? Event `.on("done")` may not be called

Comment: yes mssql so which call i should be using here to pass

Comment: Ok, I update new code. You don't need to close sql and use `on` event anymore. It is old syntax. Use Promise directly. You can read it in npm doc: https://www.npmjs.com/package/mssql